# Lexical error: Encountered: "" (0), after : ""

Tags: python, lexical

I needed to start dealing with foreign characters, and in doing so, I think I royally screwed up a file's encoding.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Lexical error at line 1, column 8.  Encountered: "" (0), after :  ""
```

The first line of the file is:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
```

Also of note: when I pasted the line above into the textarea to ask this question, and submitted, an unknown character appeared between every character (e
I have been unable to fix this issue by adding an explicit coding definition:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

I have also been unable to revert the file (using Hg) to a previous version, nor copy/paste code into a new file, or replace the broken file with copied/pasted code.

Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is indeed a zero character in there, you may find you've injected some UTF-16/UCS-2 text. That particular Unicode encoding would have a zero byte in between every ASCII character.

The best way to find out is to do a hex dump of you file with something like `od -xcb myfile.py`.

If that *is* the case, then you'll need to edit the file with something that's able to see those characters, and fix them up.

`vi` would be my first choice (since that's what I'm used to) but I don't want to start any holy wars with the Emacs illuminati. In `vi`, they'll most likely show up as `^@` characters.

Comment: Thank you! The file indeed has zero bytes in between every ASCII character.
`0000000      6d69    6f70    7472    0020    0078    006d    006c    002e
           i   m   p   o   r   t      \0   x  \0   m  \0   l  \0   .  \0
          151 155 160 157 162 164 040 000 170 000 155 000 154 000 056 000
`. How do I remove these? I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Perfect. Used vi and had to search/replace on ^@