# Gradle Build failed for the task "processBasicDebugResources" error: com.github.javaparser.TokenMgrError

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

There was some update to the XML resource file for ES Strings.  After the changes with these String the Build fails with below error:

```
Error:com.github.javaparser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 5563, column 57.  Encountered: "\u00b3" (179), after : ""
```

The error states that issue is with Superscript char \u00b3, however, I have not added this in the resource file.

To debug this issue, I run Gradlew directly from terminal with stacktrace, which give the below details:

```
Caused by: com.github.javaparser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 5563, column 57.  Encountered: "\u00b3" (179), after : ""
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParserTokenManager.getNextToken(ASTParserTokenManager.java:2480)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.jj_scan_token(ASTParser.java:9115)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.jj_3R_92(ASTParser.java:5504)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.jj_3_5(ASTParser.java:5574)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.jj_2_5(ASTParser.java:5198)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(ASTParser.java:944)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBody(ASTParser.java:865)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(ASTParser.java:470)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(ASTParser.java:932)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceBody(ASTParser.java:865)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(ASTParser.java:470)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.TypeDeclaration(ASTParser.java:398)
    at com.github.javaparser.ASTParser.CompilationUnit(ASTParser.java:203)
    at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:111)
    at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:158)
    at com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:177)
    at butterknife.plugin.FinalRClassBuilder.brewJava(FinalRClassBuilder.java:36)
    at butterknife.plugin.FinalRClassBuilder$brewJava.call(Unknown Source)
    at butterknife.plugin.ButterKnifePlugin$_apply_closure1$_closure2$_closure3$_closure4.doCall(ButterKnifePlugin.groovy:34)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:596)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:577)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
    ... 70 more
```

Could anyone please suggest on how this can be fixed, any ideas!

Comment: Simple error https://stackoverflow.com/a/6501158/4592448 Solve your error.

Comment: What you mean by `ES Strings`?

Comment: Spanish Strings

Comment: @Timson are you using the latest version?

Comment: Yes, it is the latest version @Jorgesys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say:

> There was some update to the `XML` resource file for `ES` Strings. After
>   the changes with these String the Build fails with below error:

```
Error:com.github.javaparser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 5563, column 57.  Encountered: "\u00b3" (179), after : ""
```

## What's happening

In your **Spanish** `res/values-es/strings.xml` file you have a `unicode charachter`,
  (U+00B3) ('SUPERSCRIPT THREE') at line 5563, column 57.

(Remember the `Android` `strings.xml` resource file is [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded).

## How to fix it (general fix)

This is how you encode that character in `strings.xml` (`&#x00b3`):

```
  <string name="SUPERSCRIPT THREE">&#x00b3</string>
```

## How to fix it (specific)

It is not clear how or why you are using [com.github.javaparser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) to process your resource strings instead of the default (as I know it) [XmlPullParser](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) (you have not shared your `build.gradle` file's). It is clear you are using an old (with known bugs in this area) version. To upgrade:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.javaparser:javaparser-core:3.5.5'
}
```

## Links

See [Special-characters-in-your-XML](https://support.crossref.org/hc/en-us/articles/215652783-Special-characters-in-your-XML).

Comment: After the dependencies updated, the error seems resolved!

Answer (score 0):

This issue was previously reported a as bug:

https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=270350

but this error is caused by unicode characters like ["\u00b3"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00b3/index.htm)

This issues were closed and fixed in the last version:

https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/1159
https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/issues/404
https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser/pull/411

**Upgrade to the latest version!**